# Not generating unique GUID

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I got a very weird event when storing data.
My table uses Guid as primary ID, and for some reason it is recording the same Guid for all new entries.

Table constructs

```
public class Checkpoint
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}

public class Track
{
    public Track()
    {
       Checkpoints = new List<Checkpoint>();
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public List<Checkpoint> Checkpoints { get; set; }

    public DateTime? CreatedOn { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ModifiedOn { get; set; }
}
```

Code snippet that converts from model to list of new Checkpoints stored in track.

```
var trackObject = new Track();

var checkpointList = model.Checkpoints.ConvertAll(x => new Checkpoint {Title = x.Title});

trackObject.Checkpoints.Add(checkpointList);

db.Track.Add(trackObject);
await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

Checkpoint table result (i omited the foreign key pointing to Track object):

```
ID                                     |  TITLE   |  CREATED_ON
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
c3451b2b-bb30-e711-b867-f01faf23929d   |  First   |  4/05/2017   11:16:50 AM    
c5451b2b-bb30-e711-b867-f01faf23929d   |  Second  |  4/05/2017   11:16:50 AM
c6451b2b-bb30-e711-b867-f01faf23929d   |  Third   |  4/05/2017   11:16:50 AM    
c7451b2b-bb30-e711-b867-f01faf23929d   |  Sprint  |  4/05/2017   11:16:50 AM    
c8451b2b-bb30-e711-b867-f01faf23929d   |  Home    |  4/05/2017   11:16:50 AM    
c9451b2b-bb30-e711-b867-f01faf23929d   |  Finish  |  4/05/2017   11:16:50 AM
```

As can be seen all the ID fields are the same.
Where is the fault in the code?

Comment: Did you forget to put the attribute [Key] on your Id?

Comment: They are not the same. They are all different in the first part. This is because it is a SequentialGuid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are all unique and different. Look at the second digit of these posted guids. 
The EF code tells SQL to generate new Sequential Guids (TSQL NEWSEQUENTIALID()).

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/newsequentialid-transact-sql